# How are these two expressions equal/the same?

Tags: logarithms, roots

[The expressions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9ZYZ.jpg)

I don't understand where the sqrt root goes and how we go from 1/2 to 1/4.

Comment: The image you link to does not make it clear *which* two expressions you meant to ask about.  Have a look at this [introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here, and consider editing the body of the Question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$$

So: $$\log(\sqrt{x^2+1})=\log[(x^2+1)^\frac12]=\frac12\log(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Note that $$\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$$ is not always true, take for example $$a=2$$!

Comment: $$\log t^2=2\log t$$ when $t>0$ [(see here)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hgdk4do19y). But this is irrelevant as $t=x^2+1>0 \forall x\in\Bbb R$

Comment: In this case you have right!

Answer (score 0):

You can use that $$\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$$ for $$x>0$$ and $$r\neq 0$$